# Site load problem with request headers referer HTTP

Tags: load, problem

I have a problem with my site load time. I check load time with `gtmetrix.com` and I find hard problem (my site adress: `kelishe.com`).

If you check it with `getmetrix.com` and go to timeline you see 2 request like: *get: www.kelishe.com*.

This is mean that my site load twice in one time and increase my load time.

[a busy cat http://img.ir/MHgc.png](http://img.ir/MHgc.png)

I think the problem is about request headers referer HTTP buy I don't know how I can fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second request is made by the following CSS rule (lines 46 to 50 in your HTML-output):

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
body{background:#f9f9f9 url('')    ;}
</style>
```

Apparently `url('')` is interpreted by the browser as "the current url". So this CSS rule tries to load the current URL as background but since no image is returned it fails silently.

If you either set a path like `url('/path/to/background.png')` or just remove the `url('')`-part, you should be fine.